# How to count the total number of the opened files by the users and processes on my machine

Tags: 12.04, command-line, files

I used this command to display a list of all opened files of the current user on my machine :

```
lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home
```

The result was :

[image]

I want to know the total number of the opened files , is there a quick way to get that like adding option for this command,other command or whatever ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `wc`, the option `-l` counts the lines:

```
lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | wc -l
```

This will output `25` in your case.

Additionally you can number the lines with `nl`:

```
lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | nl
```